El método filter devuelve una copia del arreglo
Estoy un poco confundido con la parte de la función. Sucede que la parte que dice eliminar la hice para que me devuelva el resultado en el array original pero me la devuelve a un nuevo arreglo hecho por el método filter.
He intentado con otros métodos, pero no logro hacer que la función retorne el valor al array original.


let arr = [];
let can = 0;
can = prompt('diga su cantidad')

for (let i = 0; i < can; i++) {
  arr[i] = prompt('diga sus nombres')
}



function d(vi, can) {
  let el;

  el = prompt('1. consultar /2. agrgar /3. eliminar /4. update /5.salir')

  if (el == 5) {
    return ""
  }
  if (el == 1) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      alert(arr[i])
    }
    return d(vi, can)
  }
  if (el == 2) {
    el = prompt('agregue su nombre')
    vi.push(el)
    return d(vi, can)
  }
  if (el == 4) {
    let a = 0
    a = prompt('diga su indice');
    el = prompt('diga su nombre')
    vi[a] = el
    return d(vi, can)
  }
  if (el == 3) {
    el = prompt('escriba el nombre a eliminar')
    c = vi.some((e) => e == el)
    if (c) {


      vi = vi.filter((e) => e != el)

    }

    console.log(vi)

    return d(vi, can)
  }
}

console.log(d(arr, can))



Traté de modificar el arreglo original, pero tampoco funcionó.

Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. 1. Mayúsculas en internet = GRITAR. 2. Pon en el título el problema específico que estás teniendo.

Tu código funciona razonablemente bien y, si bien haces un paso de más para eliminar, el arreglo si que se modifica, ya que guardas correctamente la referencia al nuevo arreglo, dentro de la función.
Los métodos como filter, splice, etc. siempre te devuelven un nuevo arreglo, eso no se puede cambiar, pues así está diseñado.
Pero, hay operaciones donde usas el arreglo que has recibido como parámetro dentro de la función, y otras donde usas el arreglo global. Al principio ambos son el mismo, pero eso va a variar después de filtrar.
No te das cuenta, porque este arreglo es global ya que está declarado antes de la función. Si cambias la declaración al final, encontrarías que la variable no está declarada. Eso hace toda la diferencia, pues dentro de la función llegas a trabajar con una copia del arreglo. Más adelante veremos por que pasa esto sin que te des cuenta.
Hay, otros problemas con el código:

En la llamada recursiva, vas creando una serie de arreglos intermedios, que existen en memoria, pero a los que se va perdiendo referencia.
Pero, para comenzar, en realidad la solución de este problema no requiere recursividad, ni es una buena solución, puesto que va dejando una pila de llamadas que es un desperdicio de recursos.
Digamos, si el usuario interactúa N veces con este menú, vamos a acabar con N copias del arreglo en memoria, con las distintas versiones que va habiendo de él.
Si este fuera un sistema que se utiliza todo el día, o por 30 días sin descanso, bueno, imaginemos la cantidad de memoria que va a requerir.
Claro, este no va a tener ese uso, pero enfocarlo de manera correcta es algo que se aprende con las cosas pequeñas.
En realidad puedes tener un ciclo que se ejecute hasta que el usuario decida salir. Una solución típica es un ciclo infinito – while (true) – que se rompe cuando el usuario selecciona la opción de salida.

Otra crítica a tu código, es la selección de nombres de variables. Nombres como arr, vi, can, el, eran típicos en los 70's, pues la memoria disponible para los compiladores era limitada. Había lenguajes que limitaban el número de caracteres que podías usar en un identificador. Pero hoy, podemos gozar de usar nombres completos en lenguaje natural, lo que hace más legible y fácil de entender el código.
Que el código sea difícil de leer hace que sea fácil pasar por alto errores de lógica, como el acceso a la variable global y no al parámetro dónde recibiste el arreglo y que es, en mi opinión, el único que debiera manipularse dentro de la función.

Declarar las variables antes de la función, es el otro componente del problema.

Finalmente, pero no menos importante, reutilizas las mismas variables con distintos propósitos. Esto suma a la confusión a la hora de utilizar el código. Pienso que es mejor declarar las variables en el ámbito correcto, con un nombre preciso, y utilizarlas para un fin único y bien definido.


Dejo una versión dónde he resuelto los problemas mencionados:


function d(nombres) {
  let opcion;
  while (true) {
    opcion = prompt('/1.consultar/2.agrgar/3.eliminar/4.actualizar/5.salir/');
    if (opcion == 1) {
      let msg = "";
      for (let i = 0; i < nombres.length; i++) {
        msg += i + ": " + nombres[i] + "\n";
      }
      alert(msg);
    } else if (opcion == 2) {
      let nuevo = prompt('agregue su nombre');
      nombres.push(nuevo);
    } else if (opcion == 3) {
      let nombre = prompt('escriba el nombre a eliminar')
      c = nombres.some((e) => e == nombre);
      if (c) {
        nombres = nombres.filter((e) => e != nombre);
      }
    } else if (opcion == 4) {
      let i = 0;
      i = prompt('diga su indice');
      cambio = prompt('diga su nombre');
      nombres[i] = cambio;
    } else if (opcion == 5) {
      return nombres;
    } 
  }
}

let nombres = [];
let cantidad = 0;
cantidad = prompt('diga su cantidad')

for (let i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {
  nombres[i] = prompt('diga sus nombres')
}

console.log(d(nombres));



He hecho algunas cosas adicionales, como dejar el código en orden según el número de las opciones. Que esté de otra manera a mi me hace mucho ruido.
Lo que no hice y me hace ruido también es el nombre de la función, pero en realidad no se me ocurrió un buen nombre, que creo que tendría que salir de la especificación. Pensé en algo como EjecutarMenúDeUsuario(), pero no me convenció. Como sea, d() es un nombre horrible. Imagino un programa donde te encuentres algo como:
  x = a();
  r(b(x));

:D Suerete con darle mantenimiento 3 años después de que lo escribiste.
Finalmente, para el borrado, digo que haces un paso de más, pues no hace falta comprobar si existe el nombre, el filtrado va a funcionar exista o no, por lo que podría simplificarse a algo como:
  let nombre = prompt('escriba el nombre a eliminar');
  nombres = nombres.filter((e) => e != nombre);




let arr = [];
let can = 0;
can = prompt('diga su cantidad')

for (let i = 0; i < can; i++) {
  arr[i] = prompt('diga sus nombres')
}



function d(vi, can) {
  let el;

  el = prompt('1. consultar /2. agrgar /3. eliminar /4. update /5.salir')

  if (el == 5) {
    return ""
  }
  if (el == 1) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      alert(arr[i])
    }
    return d(vi, can)
  }
  if (el == 2) {
    el = prompt('agregue su nombre')
    vi.push(el)
    return d(vi, can)
  }
  if (el == 4) {
    let a = 0
    a = prompt('diga su indice');
    el = prompt('diga su nombre')
    vi[a] = el
    return d(vi, can)
  }
  if (el == 3) {
    el = prompt('escriba el nombre a eliminar')
    c = vi.some((e) => e == el)
    if (c) {


      vi = vi.splice(0, vi.length, ...vi.filter((e) => e != el))


    }

    console.log(vi)

    return d(vi, can)
  }
}

console.log(d(arr, can))



Explicación
el método de array recibe tres parámetros, el primero donde empezar a eliminar, el segundo donde terminar de eliminar y le tercero el valor por el que vamos a remplazar lo eliminado.
es por ello que eliminamos todo y el arreglo que obtienes con filter lo pasamos como tercer parámetro para que sea lo único que contenga

de verdad que no iba a saber como resolver. he leido la documentacion muchas veces. pero al parecer tengo un problema con para saber utilizarlas. me gustaria saber donde aprendiste de eso. muchas gracias!!!!

@JULIAN si esta respuesta resolvió tu problema dale click al botón de aceptar que sale a la izquierda y tiene un icono de una palomita verde, si solamente fue útil te recomiendo usar el botón de flecha hacia arriba que sale a la izquierda de la pregunta también
